# JS loaded asynchronously in body keeps browser in "loading" mode

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, script-tag

I am loading some JS from an external source right before my `</body>` tag. I am experimenting to see what happens if the server hangs while trying to serve this third party JS. It seems that everything on my page works just fine, but the browser still spins as though the page is still loading. Is there a way to load this javascript in such a way that the browser won't wait on it to declare the page fully loaded?

For reference, I have tried the following two methods to load my JS asynchronously:

```
<script>
  var resource = document.createElement('script');
  resource.src = "https://myserver.com/js/myjs.js”;
  var script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  script.parentNode.insertBefore(resource, script);
</script>
```

and

```
<script async src="https://myserver.com/js/myjs.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using the `async` attribute on your script or doing something else to load it asynchronously?

Comment: @zero298 good question, I edited above to clarify

Comment: Are you saying the request never times out, it just keeps trying to load the script forever ?

Comment: nope, just that if it takes 1 minute to load, I would rather that my page be displayed as "finished" before that minute is up because this resource is not a deal breaker

Comment: So in other words, it timeouts just like any other script would without `async`, usually after a couple of minutes if nothing is set on the server, but you'd like requests that are async to timeout sooner.

Comment: more like I'd like it to quietly load in the background without the browser displaying the spinning wheel. Also, how would I go about reducing the timeout time? That could help

Comment: It's very strange that `readyState` would be `loading`.  I just tried with the `async` attribute and I'm seeing my `readyState` as `interactive`.  Are you sure you are getting `loading` or are you getting **not** `complete`?

Comment: Did you try with the async attribute on a resource that hangs for a while? I'm not sure how to check the readyState, but what I am seeing is this: I can interact with the page as normal (except the parts that rely on the third party JS which isn't loading, of course), but the browser still has a spinning wheel indicating that the page is not fully loaded

Comment: A resource that hangs, usually does that, regardless of what the resource is, or if it's async, I don't think there's any way around that.

Comment: @kat Check `document.readyState`

Comment: `document.readyState` is "interactive", but the wheel at the top of the page is still spinning, and at the bottom it still says "waiting for <myResource>..."

Comment: And it always will, until the request times out, or the browser can actually load the resource, you can't remove that **native** behaviour.

Comment: @adeneo so there is no way to load JS without blocking the browser from displaying the page as fully loaded? Is there documentation of this somewhere? Also, if that is so, how do I limit the timeout for this resource?

Comment: You can generally set timeout for requests on the serverside. Not sure where to look for documentation, probably at the browser vendors pages or something. Running your top code in a small timeout, or with an ajax request or something similar will probably solve the spinning thingy and let the page fire the onload event before trying to load the script etc.

Comment: Why do you need the browser to look loaded?  If you're waiting on a script, then you aren't really loaded.  At most, you're `interactive`.  Read the differences here: [readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState).  In interactive, you're not blocked, and can access the DOM.

Comment: @zero298 I do understand the difference, I just feel it would be a better user experience if the page appeared fully loaded since this piece of JS is not crucial

Comment: @adeneo thanks! I will try the timeout

Comment: Maybe you can set cursor to 'normal' for better user experience. However that won't make the page 'finished'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer compiled from the comments above and my own experimentation:

If you load the third party JS *after* the rest of the page has finished loading, then the browser will render the page as though it is completely loaded, even if the external resource hangs. One way to accomplish this is to load the JS within a `window.setTimeout` with a timeout greater than your page's standard load time.

When you are loading external JS through a JS function rather than through a standard script tag, remember that if you have any `data-` attributes, they belong in the `resource.dataset` object.

So, in the example above,

```
 <script async data-my-data="someData" src="https://myserver.com/js/myjs.js"></script>
```

becomes

```
<script>
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        var resource = document.createElement('script');
        resource.dataset.myData = "someData";
        resource.src = "https://myserver.com/js/myjs.js";
        var script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        script.parentNode.insertBefore(resource, script);
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Note that 5000 as a timeout works for me because my page loads in well under 5 seconds, and I don't need the JS that I am loading in the first 5 seconds. If you need yours sooner or your page takes longer to load, you will need to adjust this number. Also, as @adeneo mentioned above, another way to accomplish the same thing would be to load the js through ajax later.

Answer (score -3):

You can load js by `getscript`, check this [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQmpZY)

Comment: While this is a really bad answer, it is still an attempted answer even without the link. This should not have been flagged, and should not be [recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11192851). See: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)

Comment: For further reference, see [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).